# What are the best practices to create a TableView variable holder for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableviewer

I am suffering to find a way to create a table view variable holder that is able to hold the section and the data from that section, I told I had find a good way using the this structure

```
NSMutableDictionary[key,NSMutableArray[myClass]]
```

It work very well as far as I don't need to update the data in the class 'myClass' it hold all the sections in a dictionary and all the members of the section in the array however it has been impossible to delete or change the data from the array.

So my question is, what is the best practices to create a variable that hold details from a table view with sections?

I am using swift and XCode6

Comment: Why is it impossible to change the array? Its mutable, you should be able to change it.

Comment: I think is some bug in swift it use to work fine in object-c. I have been trying for 3 days now. I describe it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469737/changing-a-value-in-a-object-embedded-in-a-msmutablearray-embedded-in-a-msmutabl?noredirect=1#comment47104196_29469737

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for your help I find your the problem, actually my dictionary is been reload after the detail view is dismissed, I don't understand why the master details variables loses the values after call the details view